# Appeal of a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, specific-question

This question was closed while I was working on an answer, and now I can't answer it.
The person who posted the question revised it, yet it remains closed.
This question is a perfectly valid question.

It appears from searching this forum that the policy is that a question is placed on hold for five days before being closed, yet it was closed after something like 2 hours.

Question: How do I continue accessing Facebook (or other TOR-blocked websites) with TOR? Other options? [closed]
* Link: [How do I continue accessing Facebook (or other TOR-blocked websites) with TOR? Other options?](https://superuser.com/questions/608720/how-do-i-continue-accessing-facebook-or-other-tor-blocked-websites-with-tor-o)

"closed as not a real question by ... "

Comment: Closure isn’t permanent — just flag it for reopening

Comment: Do you have an answer to the question that actually involves using Tor? Because it sounds like the the original poster actually wants to know [How can I protect myself while using public wifi hotspots?](http://superuser.com/questions/18067/how-can-i-protect-myself-while-using-public-wifi-hotspots), and that question already exists. (If you have a way of getting around the block while continuing to use Tor, that's a different and more interesting matter.)

Answer (score 3):

Right at the very top of the meta post you reference, it says:

> After a ton of discussion, work and input from the community, we're rolling out the remainder of major closing changes that you've helped us design, as discussed in these prior posts.
>
> They're live on Meta today, **and will likely roll out to the rest of the network sometime next week**.

The "on hold" changes haven't been activated on Super User yet, but will be soon.

One of the changes which is already active (again, as explained in the meta post you referenced) is that questions edited by the original asker within 5 days of closure will be automatically put into the reopen queue, to be reviewed by users with enough reputation to vote to reopen:

> 2. Questions edited by the OP within five days of closure go into the re-open queue (live since Feb)
>
>    - Previously, posters often had to resort to a meta post to get an improved question considered for re-opening
>    - Now, timely edits by the OP are proactively pushed into a process for re-opening review
>
> We may consider letting non-trivial edits by others, or later edits
>   trigger addition to the queue at some point.

Given that the question has been edited by the OP and it's been less than a day, this question will already be in the reopen queue for consideration by other users. If five users vote to re-open the question, then it will be open to new answers.

I respectfully disagree that it is a "perfectly valid question," but the question was closed without any moderator intervention, and can be reopened as such as well. If the community decides that the edits are sufficient to improve the question, it will be reopened by community votes soon.

---

Update: this post didn't go into the review queue (yet) because only the title was edited, not the content of the question. If the OP edits the body of the question, it will be automatically submitted for re-consideration by reviewing users.